# How to put lists of numpy ndarrays into columns of pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have input which is formatted like so [notice there will be more than just `a` and `b`]:

```
inp = {
    "a": np.zeros((1000, 3, 4)),
    "b": np.zeros((1000, 5, 2)),
    "c": np.zeros((1000, 7, 8, 2,)),
    "d": np.zeros((1000, 6,)),
}
```

I want a dataframe with 1000 rows, and `3*4 + 5*2` *named* columns [say, a_0_0 ... a_2_3 and so on] to contain the data which resides inside `in`.

Unfortunately, this is not trivial, and searches in google or the docs or stackoverflow give unrelated answers.

What is the standard way to do this?

---

I have tried creating a df from each of `a` and `b`, then vstacking, then renaming the columns, but it seems like a huge overkill for something that should be much easier.

---

EDIT:

I am sorry, I should have mentioned arrays can be of more than 3 dimensions. size is arbitrary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`np.ndarray.reshape`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html) then use [**`np.column_stack`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html) here.

```
inp = {
    "a": np.zeros((1000, 3, 4)),
    "b": np.zeros((1000, 5, 2)),
    "c": np.zeros((1000, 7, 8, 2,)),
    "d": np.zeros((1000, 6,)),
}

arrs = [arr.reshape(1000, -1) for arr in inp.values()]
out = np.column_stack(arrs)

array([[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       ...,
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]])
out.shape
(1000, 140) # 3*4 + 5*2 + 7*8*2 + 6 = 140
```

For columns you can use [**`itertools.product`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and use [**`itertools.chain.from_iterable`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) here.

```
from itertools import product, chain
shapes = [(name, arr.shape[1:]) for name, arr in inp.items()]

def col_names(val):
    *prefix, shape = val
    names = [map(str, range(i)) for i in shape]
    return map('_'.join, product(prefix, *names))
cols = [*chain.from_iterable(col_names(val) for val in shapes)]
len(cols) # 140
cols
['a_0_0',
 'a_0_1',
 'a_0_2',
 ...
 'a_2_2',
 'a_2_3',
 'b_0_0',
 'b_0_1',
 ...
 'b_4_1',
 'c_0_0_0',
 ...
 'c_6_6_1',
 'c_6_7_0',
 'c_6_7_1',
 'd_0',
 ...
 'd_5']
```

Now use `cols` as columns in your dataFrame.

```
pd.DataFrame(out, columns=cols)
     a_0_0  a_0_1  a_0_2  a_0_3  a_1_0  a_1_1  ...  d_0  d_1  d_2  d_3  d_4  d_5
0      0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1      0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
2      0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
3      0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
4      0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
..     ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...
995    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
996    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
997    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
998    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
999    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0

[1000 rows x 140 columns]
```

Comment: nice solution! what about the column names?

Comment: @Gulzar Should names be like `a1 to a12`  and `b13 to b22`?

Comment: a_0_0..a_2_3 ... b_0_0...b_4_1 ... and so on for other names.

Comment: please see edit to question, I am sorry, should have stated that sooner.

Comment: to your question - yes. ordering the same as reshape

Comment: @Gulzar `reshape(1000, -1)` keeps 1st dim i.e rows to be 1000 and rest all dims are collapsed into columns. `reshape` would multiple dims too

Comment: This is a good solution, but I still need the names to reflect the original shape and indices. For example, `out[["a_2_3"]]` should give the corresponding of `inp["a"][:, 2, 3]`, and `out["c_5_4_1"]` should correspond to `inp["c"][:, 5, 4, 1]`

Comment: @Gulzar Updated the answer to add columns

Comment: the product trick is the neatest I've seen in months

Comment: Edited the map part because it gave an error for int to string convertion in join

Comment: @Gulzar I forgot to convert `range` to `str` (copy-paste is a hassle) :P Thanks for pointing it. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can create two dataframes and then `pd.concat` them:

```
inp = {
    "a": np.zeros((1000, 3, 4)),
    "b": np.zeros((1000, 5, 2))
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame([{'a_{}_{}'.format(i1, i2): v2 for i1, v1 in enumerate(row) for i2, v2 in enumerate(v1)} for row in inp['a']])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([{'b_{}_{}'.format(i1, i2): v2 for i1, v1 in enumerate(row) for i2, v2 in enumerate(v1)} for row in inp['b']])

print( pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1) )
```

Prints:

```
     a_0_0  a_0_1  a_0_2  a_0_3  a_1_0  ...  b_2_1  b_3_0  b_3_1  b_4_0  b_4_1
0      0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  ...    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
1      0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  ...    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
2      0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  ...    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
3      0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  ...    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
4      0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  ...    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
..     ...    ...    ...    ...    ...  ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...
995    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  ...    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
996    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  ...    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
997    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  ...    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
998    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  ...    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
999    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  ...    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0

[1000 rows x 22 columns]
```

---

EDIT: To have arbitrary number of keys:

```
inp = {
    "a": np.zeros((1000, 3, 4)),
    "b": np.zeros((1000, 5, 2))
}

dfs = []
for k, v in inp.items():
    dfs.append( pd.DataFrame([{'{}_{}_{}'.format(k, i1, i2): v2 for i1, v1 in enumerate(row) for i2, v2 in enumerate(v1)} for row in v])  )

print( pd.concat(dfs, axis=1) )
```

Comment: Please notice there are more than just `a` and `b`, there can be an arbitrary number of such entries in `inp`